# Pull in external data on each request, or store locally?

Tags: json, mongodb, database-design, architecture

My team and I are working on a project where we need to pull in data from a central source, to various client websites.

The data is stored in JSON and the central source running on Nodejs and MongoDB. The client sites are mostly Wordpress (a few other third party CMS's), and are therefore running on PHP and MySQL.

The way we've set it up, is to pull in the data (real estate listings) from the central db on each request, and display like regular HTML.

I'm worried that this will be resource intensive and will be a slower solution, given the fact that external data needs to be looked up and fetched on each request.

My question is: Is this an ideal solution? What would be better?

My first thought was to build a push/store solutions, where the central source would push out data as it was gathered, and have it stored locally on each client site. But that would obviously require some sort of database infrastructure on each client, probably making it more complicated than need be.

Thoughts?

Comment: How often do you expect data to change? Also, please explain what do you mean by client here, is it the normal user who visits a site, or different web sites which are hosted ( and hence have infra to add a DB)

Comment: In some cases, I expect the data to change on the daily. Client = client website, so the website that fetches and displays the data from the central database source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A central datasource is not bad if its on same network and does not introduce a lot of overhead. You will need to run some test to verify that calls from most clients have similar response times. If the access is not a problem, central db is equipped to handle so many clients in parallel, then having a central DB makes sense.

Disadvantage is that it makes a single point of failure. If it fails, all websites go down. Plus as load increases, if its not tuned properly, performance will degrade on all nodes.

I will suggest a distributed model.You will need a pull job every day to fetch data one time in off hours and saving it locally on each client. Hence you might need a DBA to help you with that. You will need to look at the data size and how much time it will take to refresh the data to ensure it gets over quickly. The website need not go down during that time. Plus, different clients can have a refresh at different times if needed.

I had a similar situation where my team used DB to DB replication via a batch job which runs every day in off business hours ( we only take modified/added records for replication to reduce data refresh size, you can implement a similar logic based on your data set).

As far as client getting complex, I don't think its going to make a big change in complexity from coding perspective. Your front end wont change, only the call to data ( probably a webservice) will get data from DB instead of central data store.

I will suggest to keep an layer of abstraction, fetch data via a interface which should have 2 implementations, one which gets data from central data store and one which gets from local data store. This way you can easily swap. So yes, marginally more work, but not a significant increase in complexity.

One last thing to consider is monitoring requirement. We have had issues where replication fails at times and has to be manually fired again. So that should be considered while going for local DB. You will need to look at that consideration before deploying such architecture.
This approach is more expensive as you will need more databases and possibly a DBA to monitor them.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed reply. You're saying a lot of things I had in mind too, so that's reassuring.